# How to change this Ruby regex to also include underlines?

Tags: ruby, regex

At the moment I am using this line to take a string and extract only the letters from it:

```
string.scan(/[a-zA-Z]/).to_s
```

How do I modify this so that the underline character, "_", is also included? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add it within the brackets (the *range* IIRC).

```
string.scan(/[a-zA-Z_]/).to_s
```

Answer (score 6):

Alternative version

```
string.scan(/[a-z_]/i).to_s
```